# Is is possible to use a (keras + tensorflow) machine learning model in MATLAB?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, tensorflow, keras

I was running into a situation where I want to call a neural network model that has been build using Keras + Tensorflow from MATLAB. Is it possible to do so?

In case it is impossible for MATLAB and Python to interact, is there anyway to extract the weight and bias to re-implement a similar neural network in MATLAB?

Comment: Of course you can call Python from MATLAB, just use your favourite search engine to look for that. There will be thousands of examples. Just make sure to output all relevant variables from the NN in order to read them in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [importKerasNetwork](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importkerasnetwork.html) function in Matlab.